# Regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

i Guys
I  need some help with some Regular expression:

here is the string:

```
<div style="width:477px;" id="__ss_8468630"><strong style="display:block;margin:12px 0 4px;"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.slideshare.net/Account/title" title="&#x002019;s DDM SaaS Antivirus Patch Management Solution">DDM SaaS Antivirus Patch Management Solution</a></strong> <div style="padding:5px 0 12px;"> View more documents from <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://www.slideshare.net/account">Account</a> </div> </div>
```

and I need to get just the id number .

ex. output:

**8468630**

thanks everyone

Comment: will it always be in the same format? always the same number of digits? etc?

Comment: this one (id="__ss_) is always the same

Comment: @MattBall - your sentiment is not entirely applicable in this case. He's trying to extract a portion of a string inside an HTML attribute. Yes he should use the parser to get the attribute value, but he still needs a regex or substring to get the part of the string he wants.

Comment: thanks Matt, good idea. My stupid head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regEx necessary, you can just do a simple string replace.

```
element.id.replace('__ss_',''); // => '8468630'
```

Comment: This will work, but assumes that the `__ss_` part of the string will always be the same. He didn't specify this in the question, so a regex might have been better.

Comment: He says "here is the string", which seems like a pretty specific case.  Even if the front-end of the string changes, as long as the length of the ID remains consistant you could still do it without a regex: `element.id.substr(element.id.length-7, element.id.length);` though that probably wouldn't be better than `element.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');`

Answer (score 1):

```
"__ss_8468630".match(/[\d\.]+/g); // --> [8468630]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get those digits. Although this will break if the # of digits changes.

```
\d{7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Being e the div element you could use this

```
var n = e.id.match(/__ss_(\d+)/)[1];
```

As match returns an array containing the whole match in the position 0 (__ss_8468630) and the matching groups in its same position.  Group 1 "(\d+)" (8468630)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var num = element.id.replace(/\D*/g, '' )
```